# Subscriptions register_member during subscribing doesn't work

Tags: devdemon, subscriptions

I'm setting up Subscriptions for a client; I've implemented the Subscriptions page, and it works for people who already have an account in EE, but it fails if you aren't logged in, despite register_member="yes" being set.

The error returned is:

CARD_CREATE: Email is required.

I verified that the email address is indeed in the form, and in fact, I get this error even with the Templates that come with Subscriptions.  This makes the product unusable for my client.

If it matters, I also am using SolSpace User, and I have it set up to use email addresses as usernames on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the included templates? If so, go to the template subscribe_with_register.html and it includes a fully working example.

The key is you must have register_member="yes" as a parameter and you must have at minimum these four fields: username, email, password and password_confirm. Custom fields can be added with m_field_id_1 with 1 being the field id of the custom member field.

Comment: Yes, even the included templates do not work, as I mentioned in the original post.  Here's a link to the unmodified example template that comes with Subscriptions 1.5.3:  http://www.crushlivepoker.com/subs/subscribe_with_register/basic_monthly_subscription_podcasts_only

Comment: Do you have EE settings enabled to allow new members?

Comment: Yes, I have new users enabled.  Member activation is set to "Self-activation via email".  Require terms of service is NO.

Comment: You are going to need to make a support ticket. It works in my environments, so we need to see what you have different.